# Objective-C - Publish to Facebook

Tags: objective-c, xcode, facebook

I’m wanting to create a iPhone application where the user has the option to publish data to their facebook page.

Does anyone have any sample extracts of code or reading material I can have a look to get a background understanding of what I wish to create.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you bothered yourself trying Facebook sample code at least?

https://github.com/facebook/facebook-iphone-sdk

Comment: I wasn’t sure what to search for, this is why I asked.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the official facebook developer documentation, there's a video:

http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/213/

Answer (score 0):

By far the easiest way to accomplish this is with [ShareKit](http://www.getsharekit.com/), a framework with interfaces for sharing to LOTS of different social networks.